# How to have xlwt functioning in a py2app build

Tags: python, excel, macos, xlwt, py2app

I have succesfully used xlwt to output an excel file at the end of my script, but when that script is converted into a standalone programm (using py2app), this excel is no longer produced. Other imported packages (Tkinter for a GUI) work fine and i can't find a place where this same issue is presented.
(Mac OS 10.9.5, python 2.7.5: pre-installed mac version)
(xlwt is present in /build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/python2.7-standalone/app/site-packages/)

The problem is isolated to a very small script, which outputs one excel file, with one filled cell:

```
def export_xcl():
    import xlwt

    wb = xlwt.Workbook()#initialize excel sheet
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')

    text_cells=xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman')

    ws.write(0,0, 'jaja',text_cells)

    print ('voor het saven')

    wb.save('testx.xls')

    print ('na het saven')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    export_xcl()
```

This script runs perfectly when normally started.

The executable however doesn't. The setup.py file used by py2app is the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['testx.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
app=APP,
data_files=DATA_FILES,
options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Now running the following command: $python setup.py py2app
produces the standalone programm, which on opening does not produce the excel sheet

I read on different sites that people have included xlwt script in their build without a problem, so i hope that someone can point my in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a folder named `xlsxwriter` in your `%PythonDir%\Lib\site-packages`?

Comment: it doesn't seem like it (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib). Is this the right folder i'm looking in?

Comment: I meant `xlwt`, not `xlsxwriter`

Comment: no xlwt in there as well (if i'm indeed in the correct folder)

Comment: Well I just realize you're on mac, so I'm not sure how much help this will be but I ran into this same problem with `py2exe` and couldn't find ANYTHING on the internet to help.  Everything I could find suggested adding `"includes": "xlwt"` to the `options` but I ended up having to move the raw `xlwt` folder to `%PythonDir%\Lib\site-packages` for it to finally work.  Hopefully someone can give you a better answer than that.  God luck

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem lies in the hidden folders behind MyApplication.app. When the following command is given:

```
wb.save('testx.xls
```

The excel file will be saved under MyApplication.app/Contents/Resources/testx.xls. 
To save in the same directory as the run file use the following:

```
wb.save('../../../testx.xls')
```

When an explicit location is given, this problem does not arise.